# Iterate object keys and get inner object's keys into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the keys of `Object.keys` all into one array but am having some difficulty.

Currently Im trying this but I get an array of each of the Object keys
`Object.keys(myObject).map(x=>Object.keys(myObject[x]))`

Object:

```
    {
   "a1G0R000002Sv15UAC":{
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ <---
         "test2_2":"test2"
      }
   },
   "a1G0R000002SvdYUAS":{
      "a1K0R000000yu8EUAQ":{ <---
         "test2_2":"test2"
      },
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ <---
         "string_1":"test"
      }
   },
   "a1G0R000002T4NIUA0":{
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ <---
         "string_1":"test"
      }
   }
}
```

Desired array: `["a1K0R000000ytEsUAI","a1K0R000000yu8EUAQ","a1K0R000000ytEsUAI","a1K0R000000ytEsUAI"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert the result into a single array"

```js
const myObject =     {
   "a1G0R000002Sv15UAC":{
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ 
         "test2_2":"test2"
      }
   },
   "a1G0R000002SvdYUAS":{
      "a1K0R000000yu8EUAQ":{ 
         "test2_2":"test2"
      },
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ 
         "string_1":"test"
      }
   },
   "a1G0R000002T4NIUA0":{
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ 
         "string_1":"test"
      }
   }
}

const keys = Object.keys(myObject).map(key => Object.keys(myObject[key])).flat();

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use 2 `for..in` loops. In simple words, `for..in` loop iterates over the key of an object. For more information, you can have a look at [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```js
const originalObject = {
   "a1G0R000002Sv15UAC":{
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ 
         "test2_2":"test2"
      }
   },
   "a1G0R000002SvdYUAS":{
      "a1K0R000000yu8EUAQ":{ 
         "test2_2":"test2"
      },
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ 
         "string_1":"test"
      }
   },
   "a1G0R000002T4NIUA0":{
      "a1K0R000000ytEsUAI":{ 
         "string_1":"test"
      }
   }
}

const desiredArray = []

for (let i in originalObject) {
  for(let j in originalObject[i]) {
    desiredArray.push(j)
  }
}

console.log(desiredArray)
```

Comment: thanks! I had a similar solution but was trying to see if was possible to accomplish this with `.map` or something else rather than 2 loops

Comment: Cool. Then you should go with the answer by@Addis and @ferhen.
But I guess, if you are trying to use Object.keys and map for better time complexity, I think both approach would have same time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`

```
Object.entries(myObject).map(x => Object.keys(x[1])).flat()
```